# How do furniture beetle larvae drink?

Tags: entomology, life-history, diet

I have read that the furniture beetle (Anobium punctatum) has larva that will burrow for three to four years in wood before emerging and pupating. How do they obtain water during that time if they are just eating wood?

Comment: It is likely that the oxidation of the organic compounds in the wood provides the water, much like many desert animals get their water.